# Time taken for $P$ to complete the mission

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Let $P$ be a person playing a video game. In order to win, $P$ needs to complete a mission, say mission "$M$". It took $5$ hours for $P$ to complete $M$ if $P$ faced two opponents simultaneously in the mission $M$. Also, takes $6$ hours for $P$ to complete $M$ if $P$ faced four opponents simultaneously in the mission $M$. Then how much time would $P$ take to complete the mission $M$ with eight opponents simultaneously?

This question was asked in an interview. I tried with simple arithmetic methods and ratios but failed. This may be a easy one, and I am sorry for that. Can you please help me to solve this or a hint to solve this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Insufficient data.  Is the required time linear with the number of opponents, or exponential with the number of opponents?  For example, if a bear takes $5$ hours to kill $2$ wolves, and $6$ hours to kill $4$ wolves, how many hours does the bear need to kill $8$ wolves.  One reasonable assumption is that adding $2$ opponents dropped the rate from $(1/5)$ (mission per hour) to $(1/6)$, which is a decrease of $(1/30)$.  Then, you could reason that adding $4$ more opponents would decrease by another $(2/30)$, so the result would be $(5/30) - (2/30)$.  ...see next comment

Comment: Taking the reciprocal, you would reason that you now need $10$ hours.  An alternative presumption is that doubling the number of opponents dropped the speed by $(1/30)$ so the new speed is instead $(4/30)$ which reciprocates to $7.5$ hours.  Still another reasonable interpretation is that doubling the opponents dropped the speed from $(1/5)$ to $(1/6)$, which equates to multiplying the speed by $(5/6).$  Then, you could reason that by doubling the opponenents again, you are again multiplying the speed by $(5/6).$ ...see next comment

Comment: This means that the new speed is $(1/6) \times (5/6) = (5/36)$, which reciprocates to $7.2$ hours.

Comment: It is plausible that the response that the interviewer was looking for was *insufficient data* coupled with contrasting reasonable assumptions, similar to those in my previous comments.

Comment: @user2661923 Thanks for your explanation. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only two data points we've recieved (with two enemies and with  four enemies) so it's hard to be sure. However, the most intuitive solution is that for each two extra enemies added, it takes 2 more hours. Thus, with eight enemies (which is six more than two), where M = time taken to complete the mission: $$ M = \frac{6}{2} + 5 = 8 $$ With the given information I think we can say the answer is 8 hours. Of course, you could also write this as $M = \frac{4}{2} + 6 = 8$ which is based on four enemies plus four more enemies equals 8 hours to complete M. Same answer as before.